# How to specify fill_value as np.nan or NaN in iris.load_cube

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, netcdf, iris-dataset

I am reading a netcdf file which constains the following header information.

```
dimensions:
    time = UNLIMITED ; // (312 currently)
    lon = 401 ;
    lat = 241 ;
variables:
    float time(time) ;
        time:standard_name = "time" ;
        time:units = "hours since 2020-01-21 00:00:00" ;
        time:calendar = "standard" ;
        time:axis = "T" ;
    float lon(lon) ;
        lon:standard_name = "longitude" ;
        lon:long_name = "longitude" ;
        lon:units = "degree_east" ;
        lon:axis = "X" ;
    float lat(lat) ;
        lat:standard_name = "latitude" ;
        lat:long_name = "latitude" ;
        lat:units = "degree_north" ;
        lat:axis = "Y" ;
    float tb(time, lat, lon) ;
        tb:standard_name = "brightness temperature" ;
        tb:units = "K" ;
        tb:_FillValue = -9999.f ;
        tb:missing_value = -9999.f ;
```

There are areas where the data is not available, and those areas are filled as -9999.0. So, when this data was created, I specified these areas to have the fill_value of -9999.0, following the netcdf standard.

Now, I am reading the above netcdf file like the following manner.

```
tb          =  iris.load_cube("{0:s}".format(input_file_path),"tb")
```

When I print `tb.data` I get

```
[[[-- -- -- ... 291.15032958984375 292.7417297363281 291.6527404785156]
  [-- -- -- ... 293.0906982421875 292.35272216796875 291.66082763671875]
  [-- -- -- ... 294.3814392089844 293.40570068359375 292.3965759277344]
  ...
  [312.0113220214844 310.80511474609375 309.0226135253906 ...
   293.8000793457031 291.7395935058594 295.8691101074219]
  [311.8231201171875 310.74249267578125 309.9149169921875 ...
   294.0130615234375 289.27911376953125 295.1790466308594]
  [309.64208984375 310.0537414550781 309.95196533203125 ...
   295.5054626464844 294.7171936035156 293.8650207519531]]

 [[-- -- -- ... 282.6540222167969 284.57452392578125 284.930419921875]
  [-- -- -- ... 285.3166809082031 285.3265686035156 285.5889892578125]
  [-- -- -- ... 287.7415466308594 287.42376708984375 287.1201477050781]
  ...
  [314.2368469238281 313.30059814453125 311.5663757324219 ...
   290.7585144042969 294.0787048339844 295.6382751464844]
  [314.0061950683594 313.3076171875 312.81201171875 ...
   294.6658020019531 293.7174072265625 294.44140625]
  [311.9427185058594 312.5367736816406 312.5076904296875 ...
   295.6319580078125 291.3963317871094 294.3623352050781]]

 [[-- -- -- ... 276.4613037109375 278.7796936035156 277.3859558105469]
  [-- -- -- ... 281.166748046875 280.1023864746094 280.9094543457031]
  [-- -- -- ... 282.4347229003906 282.95556640625 282.96893310546875]
  ...
  [313.38421630859375 312.5172119140625 311.1562194824219 ...
   292.87835693359375 294.84246826171875 295.73822021484375]
  [312.95501708984375 312.3735046386719 312.12713623046875 ...
   294.57147216796875 291.1443786621094 294.7926940917969]
  [311.0019226074219 311.48681640625 311.5829162597656 ...
   291.383544921875 290.3877868652344 295.3729553222656]]

 ...
```

where `--` indicates numpy masked array, not `np.nan` or `NaN`. I would like to change this `--` value to `np.nan` or `NaN` when the `iris.load_cube()` is called. Is this possible? If not, how can I change this after the `iris.load_cube()` is called and retaining the iris cube data structure?

Thanks.